# How to filter a date response to show data from today's date only?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using GET I receive an array and one of the data items is a timestamp string in the format:

```
 "date":"2017-01-11 12:19:15",
```

I have a function that needs to show specific data from this GET request for the current day only.

I think I would need to run an each loop and select only items that have the date: "2017-05-28", ignoring the "12:19:15" part.

Is there an easy and clean way to do this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Date.parse() (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to parse the date, then iterate over the list of parsed dates, only selecting those within the range you seek.

When using Date.parse(), you might want to be familiar with this [Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Comment: var orderDate = (new Date(Date.parse(JSON.data[i].date))).toDateString();

So here I am trying to make a new date from the json date string, then convert it back to a date string, but this code won't work, is there a way to do this in one statement?